# How to modify Tag in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, google-custom-search

I want to make all tags in WordPress to link to Google CSE . example. If I  click on a tag named "Stackoverflow",it is equal ask Google CSE to do a inside-web search.How to? thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you set-up the tag base url as "tag", you could redirect everything after myurl.com/tag/[...] to myurl.com/cse?s=[...]

Comment: That`s a good idea ! But could you please tell me how to setup the tag url as "tag"?I am really a super noob

Comment: Thanks for your great help !